# How to use vimeo-upload in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vimeo

I am going to upload the video to my app of vimeo in Node/Express.
I had googling and found the package to upload the video to the vimeo, it's the vimeo-upload.

But I am not sure how to use it.
Its the format is like following.

```
var uploader = new VimeoUpload({
    file: file,
    token: accessToken,
});

uploader.upload();
```

I got the accesstoken in my project and think file is the binary of video.

The problem is to get the binary from video.

Please help me!

Comment: Which library are you using? @jin li

Comment: I am using vimeo-upload:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vimeo-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issues of vimeo-upload.js as the API version of vimeo was upgraded.

The function upload() in the vimeo-upload.js, the url was changed like following.

```
me.prototype.upload = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open(this.httpMethod, this.url, true)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        // get vimeo upload  url, user (for available quote), ticket id and complete url
        if (e.target.status < 400) {
            var response = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText)
            this.url = response.upload.upload_link
            this.user = response.user
            this.ticket_id = response.ticket_id
            this.complete_url = defaults.api_url + response.complete_uri
            this.sendFile_()
        } else {
            this.onUploadError_(e)
        }
    }.bind(this)

    xhr.onerror = this.onUploadError_.bind(this)
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        type: 'streaming',
        upgrade_to_1080: this.upgrade_to_1080
    }))
}
```